# Paperclip, how to append a random stamp at the end of the file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip with my rails 3 app. I want to append a random string, nothing to long or crazy at the end of the file to cache bust the CDN. Anyone know a real simple way to do this?

Here is what I have currently:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { :thumb => "70x70>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/:rails_env/public/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    .....
```

I would like a file name like FILENAME_31313.png

Where 31313 is random every time a photo is saved.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the job done:

```
before_create :generate_random_hex

private
def generate_random_hex
  self.random_hex = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
end

Paperclip.interpolates :random_hex do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.random_hex
end
```

Then modify your paperclip settings like so:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => { :thumb => "70x70>" },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "/:rails_env/public/users/:id/:style/:basename_:random_hex.:extension",
```

Comment: thanks but also not sure about self.random_hex that field doesn't exist?

Comment: Its a private function. And yeah it would be called if a new photo is uploaded, thats the whole point of cache busting. If you keep the name the same no cache busting even though the contents of the image is diffrernt.

Comment: If they upload a new file then yeah it is different and the path changes, if they just edit a title or something the path for the photo wouldn't change.

Answer (score 5):

Paperclip (now?) supports this out of the box:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"},
    :url => "/system/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_secret => Test2::Application.config.secret_token
```

That way, the images are stored at `/system/000/000/006/thumb/1c4fef2bf61f39193f8606521e880cbde54e04a1.jpg`. Not short, though. With `:basename` you could add the basename to the url. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#uri-obfuscation for more details.