# Paperclip giving wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Iḿ using Paperclip 4.1.1 with default url and path. The problem is, when I try to get the image url, like that:

```
Picture.first.image.url
```

It returns:

```
"/system/pictures/images/000/000/001/original/narnia-5.jpg?1393114864"
```

But that url is wrong there is no ?1393114864, the name is just "narnia-5.jpg". And I did not set any path or url, I'm using paperclip default options. How do I fix that? And why is paperclip giving me that unexistent suffix code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the timestamp of the field updated_at. It is there for caching purposes. [By default, it is turned on in paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb).
If you don't want it, you can just pass this option in your attachment definition:

`use_timestamp: false`

Comment: I see. But why is paperclip not adding the timestamp to the image name when saving the image? If I'm using Paperclip defaults that should be done, right?

Comment: Paperclip does not store that information in the database. It just adds the timestamp to the url when you ask for the image. By attaching it, it tells the webserver to use the cache version or to download a new one.

Comment: Is there a way to config paperclip to automatically add the Timestamp when it saves the image in my public/system folder?

Comment: Try this solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136473/paperclip-how-to-append-a-random-stamp-at-the-end-of-the-file